# How to check which web elements that are truly clickable?

Tags: html, selenium, browser, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am experimenting with web-crawling techniques with python and selenium webdriver in win10 and firefox.
I encountered the following typical page with a pop-up box asking for consent to allowing for cookies.

https://irs.thsrc.com.tw/IMINT/

There are only the following two clickable tags in the page with the following xpaths.

//html/body/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a[1]

//html/body/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1]

People here suggested that I can first get an element via webdriver and then use the two methods of is_enabled() and is_displayed() to together check if the element is clickable.
However, when I get elements with the following statement:

e = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))

I found that all elements (even those in the shadow) that I got via the above statement are both enabled and displayed.
But in fact in the browser,  only the two actionable elements in the pop-up message box were clickable.
All the other elements were in the shadow and cannot be clicked (or actionable).

Can someone tell me how to get the correct information which elements are actually actionable via some API ?

Thank you very much.

Farn

Comment: Are you talking about elements that are "under" something like a popup dialog? Those are clickable... Selenium just throws an error because a user can't click them. There is no way using Selenium to identify elements that Selenium is able to click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So in general there is no algorithmic way to identify those truly clickable elements ?